# Hibernate - lazy = true

Tags: java, hibernate

I am using [Hibernate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hibernate_%28Java%29) to do mapping. One of my classes have a set of `long`s. I'd like to set `lazy` to true when fetching this object. Would it cause problem if I fetch an object and after a while use the set inside it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `lazy` attribute is applicable to child entities.  If an entity is child relationship is fetched lazily, then it isn't fetched from the database until your application tries to access it.

`lazy` wouldn't apply to a 'set of longs'.  I'm not even sure what you mean by that.  If you literally have a set of just numbers, I would hack and, write a method to create a String comprised of the longs, and not worry about lazy loading it.

Users often run into problems with `lazy` because they try to access a lazy collection after the session is closed.  Because hibernate will fetch the relevant objects only when they are accessed, if the session is closed, it's a problem -- this is the dreaded `LazyInitializationException`.